# Add auto-updating image to Google Docs from Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, images

I have several images in a Google Drive folder. I have added them to a Google Docs I'm working on (via Google Drive option).

I often have to modify the images (keeping the same titles and path). I'd like my Google Docs to detect when my images are changed and automatically update to the newest version of the images.

Is this possible?

Comment: Tried a quick google search, and on the Google Product forums, it says this is not possible with Google Docs.  They suggest using a plugin, but the only one people commented about was LucidChart, which isn't what you're looking for.  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/PKBmxUI3sUo

Comment: Agreed, I'm only able to pull through image updates by going to Tools > Linked objects and then clicking the "Update" button(s).

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with a workaround.

1. Add your images to your Google Drive.
2. Insert images from the "Insert > Image > Drive" option into your document

Once you reload the document, changes to the image show up (images do not update in real-time).

The limitation of this workaround is that the system maintains the aspect ratio of the original image. So, if you crop your image, then you have to manually resize the pasted image in Google docs.

Answer (score 0):

For this you must actually paste a new version of the image into google docs. As google docs cannot be embedded without you needing to code it in.